# problems installing ReactiveUI via nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, reactiveui

I have a basically empty VS2012 class library project that I'm attempting to add ReactiveUI to. I've already used Nuget to install NLog and Reactive Extensions. When I try to install the ReactiveUI 3.99 I get the following error log.

UPDATE: I was able to add the ReactiveUI references manually w/o Nuget and they seem to work fine.

```
------- Installing...reactiveui 3.99.4-beta -------
Attempting to resolve dependency 'reactiveui-core (= 3.99.4-beta)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Main (= 2.0.20823)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Interfaces (≥ 2.0.20823)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Core (≥ 2.0.20823)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Linq (≥ 2.0.20823)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-PlatformServices (≥ 2.0.20823)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'reactiveui-nlog (= 3.99.4-beta)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NLog (≥ 2.0.0.2000)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'reactiveui-xaml (= 3.99.4-beta)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Xaml (= 2.0.20823)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'reactiveui-testing (= 3.99.4-beta)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Testing (= 2.0.20823)'.
'reactiveui-core 3.99.4-beta' already installed.
'reactiveui-nlog 3.99.4-beta' already installed.
'Rx-Xaml 2.0.20823' already installed.
'reactiveui-xaml 3.99.4-beta' already installed.
'Rx-Testing 2.0.20823' already installed.
'reactiveui-testing 3.99.4-beta' already installed.
'reactiveui 3.99.4-beta' already installed.
Added file 'packages.config'.
Added file 'packages.config'.
Failed to add reference to 'ReactiveUI'.
==============================
```

Here is my project file's references:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="NLog">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NLog.2.0.0.2000\lib\net40\NLog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Reactive.Core">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Rx-Core.2.0.20823\lib\Net45\System.Reactive.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Reactive.Interfaces">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Rx-Interfaces.2.0.20823\lib\Net45\System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Reactive.Linq">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Rx-Linq.2.0.20823\lib\Net45\System.Reactive.Linq.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Reactive.PlatformServices">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Rx-PlatformServices.2.0.20823\lib\Net45\System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug at the moment, create either a .NET 4.0 project or a WinRT project, and it will work. Sorry about that.

**Update:** This is now fixed, check out ReactiveUI 4.0 Preview 5